# Write performance between Filesystem and Database

Tags: database, performance, file-io

I have a very simple program for data acquisition. The data comes frequently (around 5200 Hz). One piece of data has around 24 kB, so it is around 122 MB/s.

What would be more efficient only for storing this data? Saving it in raw binary files, or use the database? If the database, then which? SQLite, or maybe some other?

The database, of course, is more tempting, because when saving it to file I would have to separate them by delimiters (data can have different sizes), also processing data would be much easier with the database. I'm not sure about database performance compared to files though, I couldn't find any specific pieces of information about it.

[EDIT]
I am using Linux based OS and SSD disk which supports writing up to 350 MB/s. Data will be acquired with that frequency all the time (with a small service break every day to transfer the data to another machine)

Comment: Your question is missing some critical data... What OS are you using? How long do you acquire for at a time? Is the data readily compressible? What does your disk(s) subsystem look like?

Comment: Also, are you really worried about the write performance, because part of your question talks about subsequent *"ease of use"* which is a totally different issue - you can potentially address *"ease of use"* by transforming your data after acquisition. So is the problem really acquisition? Or ease of use?

Comment: I edited my question. My priority is performance, but I am also taking into account ease of use.

Comment: That is 7GB/minute or 430GB/hr or 10TB/day. I would be thinking of a 2-threaded program, one thread acquiring and one thread writing and 2-8 buffers between the two to allow slight speed mismatches, e.g. when the disk is syncing or doing other OS stuff temporarily. I would write raw binary to files and probably start a new file every 1-10 minutes naming each with the start time. That would minimise data loss in case of corruption and also allow you to copy files off the system without stopping acquisition. YMMV.

Comment: Also, I assume you are aware of M.2 NVME disks which can achieve maybe 4x the bandwidth of SATA-attached SSDs because of the reduced protocol overhead.

Comment: I didn't want to go into specifics of the implemenation in order to make my question more general, but yes, I am using 2 threads, one for reading, and one for writting. However I don't really understand how using "2-8 buffers" would be helpful in this situation. Right now I am queueing the data between the threads to compensate for disk syncing.

Comment: I think my *"few buffers"* are the same as your queue - just slightly different terminology. Try acquiring (reading) from `/dev/zero` as your source for performance testing of the disk subsystem to find its flat-out max speed.

Answer (score 0):

The `file system` is useful if you are looking for a particular file, as operating systems maintain a sort of index. However, `the contents of a txt file won't be indexed`, which is one of the main advantages of a database.

Another point is `understanding the relational model` meaning how you design your database, so that data doesn't need to be repeated over and over.

Moreover `understanding types` is inportant as well. If you have a txt file, you'll need to parse numbers, dates, etc.

For the performance point of view I would say that `DB are slower to start` (is usually faster to open a file than open a connection to a db). However once they are open I can guarantee that DB is faster then XML or whatever file you are thinking to use. BTW this is the main `purpose of a database: manage huge amount of data, filesystems are made for storing files`.

Last points for `DB is that they usually can handle multi-threading and concurrency` problems, which a file cannot and last but not least important `in a database you cannot delete a file by mistake` and loose your data

*So my choice would be a DB and anway I hope that providing you some info you can decide what is best for you*

**-- UPDATE --**

Since you your needs are more specific now I tried to dig deeper: I found some solutions that could be interesting for you however I don't have experience in any of them to provide you a personal suggestion about them:

- [SharedHashFile](https://github.com/simonhf/sharedhashfile): SharedHashFile is a lightweight NoSQL key value store / hash table, a zero-copy IPC queue, & a multiplexed IPC logging library written in C for Linux. There is no server process. Data is read and written directly from/to shared memory or SSD; no sockets are used between SharedHashFile and the application program. APIs for C, C++, & nodejs. However keep an eye out for issues because this project seems to be no longer maintained on Github
- [WhiteDB](http://whitedb.org/) another NoSql database that claims to be really fast, go to the speed section of their website to consult it
- [Symas](https://symas.com/lightning-memory-mapped-database/) an extraordinarily fast, memory-efficient database

Just take a look at them and if you ever use them just provide here a feedback for the community

Comment: I would use binary files because form of data is some header(time) and binary data. I'm not sure if databases could save data that fast. My priority is to save all the data in real time. Moreover I don't need concurrent access since data will be processed at another machine after transferring it.

Comment: Actually there are formats for binary data but I never used it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/jdbc-binary-data.html

Comment: Thank you for interesting propositions, I've read it and I am impressed with efficiency of those solutions, however in my case, when I have to manage about 430 GB/h all solutions based on using RAM memory are out of question. I am using a regular machine with 16 GB of RAM.